# Why does the nested PreferenceScreen not open when using AndroidX?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-preferences, androidx, preferencefragment

I am using AndroidX's Preference library to manage my app's settings. My `SettingsFragment` derives from `PreferenceFragmentCompat` and loads the following layout:

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen
        android:key="screen_backup_key"
        android:title="@string/local_database">

        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:key="button_save_key"
            android:title="@string/export" />

        <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:key="button_load_key"
            android:title="@string/_import" />

    </androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>

    <androidx.preference.Preference
            android:key="screen_about"
            android:title="@string/about" />

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

The layout is displayed correctly, but when I click on the nested `PreferenceScreen` entry nothing happens. It worked before with the `PreferenceScreen` from the *Support Library*, which is now deprecated.

I would expect to see the contents to this nested `PreferenceScreen`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not supported anymore in AndroidX's Preference Library.

> Declaring nested hierarchies within the same XML resource using a
>   nested `PreferenceScreen` is no longer supported. You should use
>   nested Fragment objects instead.

You need a separate `PreferenceFragmentCompat` for each separate screen.

> If you have a large number of Preferences or distinct categories, you
>   can display them on separate screens. Each screen should be a
>   `PreferenceFragmentCompat` with its own separate hierarchy. Preferences
>   on your initial screen can then link to subscreens that contain
>   related Preferences.

You do it like this:

> To link screens with a Preference, you can declare an `app:fragment` in
>   XML, or you can use `Preference.setFragment()`. Set the full package
>   name of the `PreferenceFragmentCompat` that should be launched when the
>   `Preference` is tapped, as shown below:

```
<Preference
    app:fragment="com.example.SyncFragment"
    .../>
```

Here is the [source](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/organize-your-settings) for further reading.

Comment: I never thought this was possible ...as the name "screen" might suggest.

Comment: But it was and actually I structured my preferences like that. See this paragraph which implies that: "Declaring nested hierarchies within the same XML resource using a nested PreferenceScreen is no longer supported. You should use nested Fragment objects instead.". Since at first I didn't find anything about it, I thought it would be a good idea to share my findings. But maybe I was the only one doing it like this :D

Comment: @MartinZeitler I forgot to tag you. See above :)

Comment: I hope that androidx.preference library will develop this feature soon, so far stay with android.preference